# Does the $\lim_{z \to -1} \sqrt{|z|} \,e^{i\operatorname{Arg}(z)/2}=i$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I am asked to show whether or not the $\lim_{z \to -1}f(z)$ where $f(z)=\sqrt{|z|} \,e^{i\operatorname{Arg}(z)/2}$ exists.

Simply plugging in $-1$ into the limit, we get, $$\lim_{z \to -1} \sqrt{\left|-1\right|}\: e^{i\operatorname{Arg}(-1)/2}\\=\lim_{z \to -1} e^{i\operatorname{Arg}(-1)/2}$$

The major problem I am facing is figuring out what the $\operatorname{Arg}(-1)$ is going to be. After doing some research, I came across a Wolfram Alpha article which said the $\operatorname{arg}(-1)=\pi$. I am assuming this holds true for the principal argument as well. Solving, we get, $$\lim_{z \to -1} e^{i(\pi/2)}=\cos\frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{2}=i$$

Although, I need some help in proving why the $\operatorname{Arg}(-1)=\pi$. Unfortunately, I was not able to find much information about it online, so I would appreciate some assistance.

Comment: There seems to be a problem. We get different answers on where $Arg(z)$ tends to depending on how $z$ approaches -1. If you approach from above or on the real axis, $Arg(z)$ would tend to $\pi$ as you approach -1. This gives the expected limit of $e^{i \pi/2}=i.$ However, if you approach from below the real axis, $Arg(z)$ would tend to $-\pi$ as you approach -1 and one obtains $e^{-i \pi/2}=-i$ instead.

Comment: Actually this result makes a lot of sense for me; at least for the complete version of this problem. I have solved the previous parts and have written my results for the relevant parts. Please refer to this image: https://imgur.com/1hBxs5R

Comment: There you go. It seems that one of the points of the exercise is to be wary of misusing your intuition in predicting the behavior of functions obtained from branches of multifunctions.

Comment: Am very interested in knowing; how did you go about understanding how $Arg(z)$ tends to act as you approach from the different axes? To put it simply, how did you figure out that $Arg (z)$ was approaching  $\pm i$ from the different directions? I have always thought about finding $Arg (z)$ by applying the $tan^{-1}(y/x)$ (where $y$ is the imaginary part and $x$ is the real part).

Comment: The motivation behind this comes directly from looking at how $Arg$ is defined. Mainly, that it takes its values on $(-\pi,\pi]$ (an angle for the input when the input is expressed in polar form). This information tells us that if any discontinuities or odd behavior arises, it is likely to have something to do with the discontinuity on the negative real axis; in particular, if it is approached from below (clockwise) or from above (counterclockwise).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- " I came across a Wolfram Alpha article which said the
  $\arg(−1)=\pi$. I am assuming this holds true for the principal
  argument as well. "

  $\pi$ ***is*** the principal argument of $−1$, i.e., Arg$(-1)=\pi.$

  But in general, $\arg(−1)=(2k+1)\pi,$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}.$
- " I have always thought about finding $\arg(z)$ by applying the
  $\tan^{−1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right).$ "

  This formula doesn't generally work, since
  $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \in
     \left(-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right),$ which doesn't even span the
  principal range $\left(-\pi, \pi\right]$ of $\arg(z)$:
  $$\displaystyle\text{Arg}(-1-i)=-\frac34\pi \\\neq \frac{\pi}4
     =\tan^{−1}\left(\frac{-1}{-1}\right).$$

The given limit $$\lim_{z\to-1} \sqrt{|z|} \exp\left(i\frac{\text{Arg}(z)}2\right)$$ doesn't exist because $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to-1}\frac{\text{Arg}(z)}2$ (and in fact, $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to-1}\frac{\arg(z)}2$) has two *non-overlapping* representations $\displaystyle\pm\frac{\pi}2$ on the Argand diagram, as hinted by F. Tomas in the comments.